# Proving $\int_{0}^{a}dx\int_{0}^{x}dz\int_{0}^{z}f(y)dy=\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{a}(a-x)^2 f(x) dx$, where $f(x)$ is continuous on $[0; a]$ & $a>0$,

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

With $f(x)$ being continuous on $[0; a]$ and $a > 0$, prove that $$\int_{0}^{a}dx\int_{0}^{x}dz\int_{0}^{z}f(y)dy = \frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{a}(a-x)^2 f(x) dx$$

This is the final question of a final exam 7 years ago at my university. Normally I would skip this one if I ever encounter it but I guess I will try to understand it this time.

I tried converting the intervals but it didn't do much since I'm not sure how to deal with $f(y)$. Also tried isolating $\int_{0}^{a} dx$.

Am I going the right way, or is there an another way that I haven't thought of?

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: You can find more duplicates with https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Cint_%7B0%7D%5E%7Ba%7Ddx%5Cint_%7B0%7D%5E%7Bx%7Ddz%5Cint_%7B0%7D%5E%7Bz%7Df(y)dy%20%3D%20%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B2%7D%5Cint_%7B0%7D%5E%7Ba%7D(a-x)%5E2%20f(x)%20dx%24